# How to print graph in graphview in odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I need to print graph in pdf or png or other format, I am using web_graph inbuild module:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LSUQ.pnge of

while print through browser I am getting only half picture

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems. Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Do you want to add an image to your own repport ??

Comment: No, I have able to draw report with my customized module and I get the above graph, I need print that graph view in .png or pdf format  which might be inbuild print option or should I create

Comment: You need to add this tag `<img src='/your_module/static/img/graph.png' style="max-height: 245px;"/>`

Comment: where should I add above line?

Comment: where should I add this tag bro??